# Model is null in View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-4.5

I have a Model which consists of properties, this Model is referenced in my View Model.

I am changing the value of the Model properties programatically (getting data from the DB).
When these values are changed, the "OnPropertyChanged" event is fired within the model, as expected.

However, my view is not being updated with these changes.

Debugging my view model reveals that the model is null.

Pretty new to MVVM and have followed tutorials for a while, but can't seem to figure this out.

My code is as follows (irrelevant parts omitted)

**Model**

```
 class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _SurName;
    private string _Email;
    private string _ContactNo;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedEvent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { PropertyChangedEvent += value; }
        remove { PropertyChangedEvent -= value; }
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChangedEvent != null)
            PropertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**View Model**  (Don't think i need the property changed stuff here but put it in anyway just in case)

```
class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public User UserModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        var test = UserModel.FirstName;

    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedEvent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { PropertyChangedEvent += value; }
        remove { PropertyChangedEvent -= value; }
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChangedEvent != null)
            PropertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**View**

```
    <Window x:Class="ProjectName.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProjectName.ViewModels">


    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>


   <Grid Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainGrid}">
        <Label Content="Logged in as:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,0,200,0"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=UserModel.FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,0,150,0"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

**User Model set here**

```
 public bool Login(string email, string password)
    {

        var userOb = new Models.User(); // new instance of user object

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(FactoryManager.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_login", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    string dbHash = null;
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dbHash = dr[1].ToString(); // get db hash value from reader
                    }

                    // if password hash matched DB then log in
                    if (Encryption.ValidatePassword(password, dbHash))
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        GetUser(userOb, email); // gets the current user
                        return true; // logged in
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return false; //invalid login
                }

            }
        }

    }

    // gets the logged in user and populates the user object, returns this
    public Models.User GetUser(Models.User userOb, string email)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(FactoryManager.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getUser", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        userOb.ID = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                        userOb.FirstName = dr[1].ToString();
                        userOb.SurName = dr[2].ToString();
                        userOb.Email = dr[3].ToString();
                        userOb.ContactNo = dr[4].ToString();
                        //Password = dr[4].ToString();
                        //loginAttempts = dr[5].ToString(); 
                    }

                    // GET ALLOCATED LINES AND POPULATE THE OBJECT

                }
                else
                {
                    return null; //invalid login
                }

            }
        }

        return userOb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's `null`.

You have the `UserModel` property in your `MainWindowVM`, but you don't initialize it anywhere (at least not in the code you pasted).

There should be a `UserModel = new User(/* arguments */);` somewhere in the view model code.

Comment: But then initializing a new model in the VM resets all the properties, the properties are updated before the view is shown

Comment: Where do you set the `UserModel` property then? Can you please paste that in your post? Usually these are set via constructor injection, property injection, simply from outside where the viewmodel is newed up (not the case here), in the view model itself (a service call for example). These come to mind right now. I don't see any of these here.

Comment: Updated my question.. sorry for any irrelevant code

Comment: When and where are these methods called? The `Login` and `GetUser`. I would say you somehow have to assign that `User` instance returned by the `GetUser` method to your view model's `UserModel` property. If these sit inside lets say a service called `LoginService` you'd normally inject that in your view model's  constructor and call some method on it which returns the `User`: `UserModel = _loginService.GetUser();`

Answer (score 0):

UserModel doesn't support INPC itself so changing it won't update the view. You've also added INPC to your model, where it generally doesn't belong.

To be honest I think you need to pick up a few books on how MVVM works, but I'll try and give a few initial pointers. Your MainViewModel needs something like this:

```
    private UserViewModel _User;
    public UserViewModel User
    {
        get { return this._User; }
        set { this._User = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

You user class will typically come from your data layer, so it generally won't do INPC, particularly if you're doing code-first development:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

(*There are exceptions to this, but let's keep things simple for now).

Your view model is the glue between the two that forms the binding between the view and the view model, so something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    private User Model;

    public UserViewModel(User model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return this.Model.ID; }
        set { this.Model.ID = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.Model.FirstName; }
        set { this.Model.FirstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    // etc
}
```

Yes, this means any fields that need to be both edited in your UI and also need to respond to changes in the underlying view model have to be duplicated in both the view and view model layers. There are ways to add it automatically to the model layer, but it typically requires implementation-specific modifications to your model and/or database layers, so I won't cover it here.

The point to take from all this is that the view model is exactly that: a logical representation of your view that provides INPC for consumption by the view. If you want code to modify a model, and you want that change to be reflected in the view, then you have to do it via the view model so that the change gets propagated through.

Comment: Any chance you could define INPC?

Comment: @RichardJune [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), if you're using a lib like MVVM Lite it'll be done for you in the base view model class, otherwise you have to add it yourself. Either way you do have to raise the changed event in the  property setters themselves.